# How do I run the pageViewController instantiation after the query?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to add imported parse information to a pageviewcontroller, but it keeps crashing because all the arrays are nil, and the second function is being called to early. How do I fix this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.retrieveInfo() { () -> () in
        self.testRetrieveInfo()
    }

}


func retrieveinfos(handleComplete:(()->())){

 let query = PFQuery(className: "Animals")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if(error == nil){
                for object in objects!{     
                    if let importname = object["Name"] as? String{
                        self.name.append(importname)
                        print(self.name)
                    }
                }

            }else{
                    print(error)
            }
        }
      handleComplete()
   }
}


func testRetrieveInfo(){

        //Setup here the PageViewController
        self.pageViewController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageVC") as? UIPageViewController //Crashes here, with fatal error fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, I checked the logs and all the arrays are empty
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as? Animal
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC!)
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward , animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
        print("called")

}
```

Comment: the code you have shown doesn't make a lot of sense; you are instantiating a view controller but not saving a reference to it. Also, you are thinking about the loading the wrong way. You should code so that it doesn't crash if arrays are nil/empty and then refresh the views once the load is complete

Comment: I am following this guide https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial, and I have implemented everything